# Version controlling software between products

Tags: c#, git, svn, version-control

I ran into an argument with a colleague about how we should do version control of our software, and I would like some input on what's the best way to do things.

We are making software for larger machines that our company are building.
This means we have specific software for every different piece of machine in our catalog, but there's also differences in software between the machines of the "same type".

The software consist of two parts, one part is our "general library", this library is used on all our machines, and the second part is the "machine specific code" which utilizes the general library but lets us write specific code for the machine. This all lives in a huge mono-repo.

Now to my issue. This general library that we have is quite fluid, there's no versioning of it (like version 1.0.0 or 2.0.0) at all (another thing I would like to address, but that's another issue). So - after we've finished a machine and ship it to our customers we keep updating the general library with new ideas and re-write things and so on. But, it's quite common for us to have to make changes to that machine later down the line. When that happens, we open up that machine-project and then we have to spend time to make it work again, since changes we made to the general library sometimes breaks things in this machines specific code.
To add to this, we have no tests or anything, so there's no easy way to know if everything is working properly again.
I'm quite new to the team and proposed that when a machine is "done", we should make a separate branch to store a snapshot of that machines code (i.e, keep a version of the general-library used at that time and the machine-specific code). To me, this means that we easily can update the machines and KNOW that the code we're looking at is the same as the code in the machine, i.e working properly. And it also lets us import a new version of that general-library if we want to, but we don't have to.

But this was met with a big no, we should make sure we never "mess up" the general library, and I was told having a lot of branches was a bad idea.
My "team" is just me and a senior colleague who has been working here a long time, so I have no one but him to discuss this with. He's also very against branches in general, everything is always in the main branch and commits goes straight into that branch, very different way of working from what I am used to.

Can someone provide some input on our case? We tend to have quite different approaches to things.

Comment: Digression: Can our suggestion really influence the thoughts of that senior colleague? And even if you succeed, you must be responsible for the changes you make afterwards. Are you willing?

Comment: this is nothing you can solve using software. You need to *convince* others about a **process**, not a bout a specific **technology**. You can only convince others with hard facts, e.g. by **measuring** how long it takes to switch between machines and to setup a new one.

Comment: Maybe this is a better fit for softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ ?

Answer (score 0):

I probably agree with your colleague that branches is a poor solution. It can easily create situations where different branches have different bugs fixed, with no practical way to merge them.

One approach is to structure your code with the library in one project, and different projects for each machine, all in the same solution. Any changes to the library require you to at least fix any compiler errors.

Another solution is to actually keep versions for your library. Put the library in a different repository and publish it to a nuget server. This allow different machine specific projects to depend on different versions of the library. However, this still require discipline to keep track of backward incompatible changes to the library. Consider using semantic versioning and bump the major version when making a backward incompatible change. One problem is that it is not always easy to figure out if a change can cause issues or not.

In either case you need some testing strategy. At least some automated tests should probably be used. But ideally you should keep one of each type of machine to use for testing if you want to be serious about supporting different machines.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cultural problem. From my experience this is not atypical for a small to mid-sized hardware-centric shop. Money is earned by selling machines, software is just a necessary evil. Your teammate is probably "the software guy" who has *a lot* of experience with the company, maybe from the start.

Now you're the new guy and make a lot of noise with your "crazy ideas" about testing and versioning.

You could look for another place where they do software development right and leave the company.

Until that happens, you will have to adapt to their way of doing things (flawed as it may be). They call the shots. You cannot work against your employer (not for long, at least).

You are not completely without options. Take little steps to improve the situation. You can try and set up your own clone of the company's VCS and do branches or tags for yourself. Or you could write tests for an isolated module (use their words: you're making sure you don't mess up the library). Introduce static analysis (I simply assume they don't do it). Do this *in addition* to your regular work. Be helpful, be supportive. Measure your impact, preferably using *their* metrics. See what works and what doesn't.

*Convince* them that your way of doing things is better. Never imply that their way of doing things is bad.